# Merging shapefile with respect to attribute using ArcMap or ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, dissolve

I have road vector file with duplicate names (3000 + entries). I want to merge them as per their name so single feature appears against one road name.

How to do it in ArcMap 10.5 or with ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should try the [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool because that:

> Aggregates features based on specified attributes.

In your case the features are lines representing your roads, and the attribute to use is their road name field.